# why `new Array(5).map((x,y)=>y*2)` didn't work? while `new Array(5).fill(1).map((x,y)=>y*2)` work?

Tags: javascript

I was trying to create an array which is [1,2,3,...,n], so I used code `new Array(10).map((value,index)=>index+1)`, but I got `[empty × 5]`;

Meanwhile, `new Array(10).fill(1).map((value,index)=>index+1)`, why?

How did Array.prototype.map() work?

My code:

```js
// [empty × 10]
new Array(10).map((value,index)=>index+1)

// [1,2,...,10]
new Array(10).fill(1).map((value,index)=>index+1)
```

Comment: map runs on assigned indexes only https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Description

Comment: You can use this: `[...Array(10)].map((_,i) => i+1);`

Answer (score 0):

As per [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Description):

> map calls a provided **callback function** once for each element in an array, in order, and constructs a new array from the results. **callback is invoked only for indexes of the array which have assigned values**, including undefined. **It is not called for missing elements of the array (that is, indexes that have never been set, which have been deleted or which have never been assigned a value)**.

---

In your first case, You are just creating an array of a certain length without setting any value so it won't call the map callback. In the second method, you are setting all values to `1` using `Array#fill` method so it will call the callback since the value is assigned for all index.

---

You can use [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#Using_arrow_functions_and_Array.from) method with a map callback for generating an array.

```js
const arr = Array.from({ length: 10 }, (_, i) => i + 1)

console.log(arr)
```